# How to determine the memory footprint of all variables

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, memory-management

I have a program without memory leaks (analysis with valgrind). Nevertheless, the program runs into a `std::bad_alloc`. My manual approximation of the memory consumption tells me that the memory should be sufficient for this program run.

I don't know which variable is consuming so much memory. The variable, where the `std::bad_alloc` is thrown is rather small.

Is there a convenient way  to determine the current footprint of all variables, objects, etc.?

Can the memory footprint be nicely visualised?

Available are totalview, the intel tools (such as Amplifier, Inspector) for Linux and VisualStudio for Windows.